# SELECT $ (dollar sign)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have good experience in SQL Server, 
But suddenly I discovered this strange `SELECT` command

```
SELECT $
```

or

```
SELECT $ FROM tableName
```

All the time it returns zero scalar value (`0.00`),
or a new column with all values of `0.00`

What is that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When SQL Server comes across your `$` sign, it automatically converts it into a `money` data type. Because you don't have an explicit value after the dollar sign, SQL Server is assuming `0.00`. From [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172602%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> When converting to `money` or `smallmoney`, integers are assumed to be monetary units. For example, the integer value of 4 is converted to the money equivalent of 4 dollars (for us_english, the default language). Numbers to the right of the decimal in floating-point values are rounded to four decimal places for money values. Expressions of data types char or varchar that are being converted to an integer data type must consist only of digits and an optional plus or minus sign (+ or -). Leading blanks are ignored. Expressions of data types char or varchar converted to money can also include an optional decimal point and leading dollar sign ($).

Comment: thank you,
that's great, but i cannot use it with any fields for example 
select $ unitprice from Products
in northwind returns a new row with the name and all 0.00 also,
it seems like useless if it should be used with explicit numbers

Answer (score 11):

After a little messing around, I've figured since this happens no matter what currency symbol is used, SQL server is implying that the field is a currency field.

If you add numbers after the currency symbol, in this case a dollar so:

```
SELECT $4
```

SQL server will return 4.00

So SQL Server is taking the use of $ and assuming we want to create a field with the *MONEY* datatype and as we haven't entered a value after the currency symbol, SQL Server assumes the value is 0, though in my opinion this should return NULL.

Comment: thank you,
that's great, but i cannot use it with any fields for example 
select $ unitprice from Products
in northwind returns a new row with the name and all 0.00 also,
it seems like useless if it should be used with explicit numbers

Comment: @HusseinFawzy SQL is a whole programming language, it's not just used for querying tables. For example, this would be used for insert statements, or for `WHERE unitprice < $1`. Its usability within the select columns is just because of the uniform design of the language. The fact that you think being used with explicit numbers is useless implies you think explicit numbers are themselves useless.

Comment: @HusseinFawzy when yuo have a field in a query and the put a space after it and then some text, SQL defines that as cresting an alias for the field. That's basic SQL syntax. I put select 1234 amount it would do the same thing or if I put select myfield amount from Finance it would do the same thing.So why would think that was an unexpected result?

Comment: And yes it is not the most useful construct and you can easily get away with never using it.  You can always cast directly to a money datatype if you need to.  Its just a  little trick that may reduce the total number of characters you type.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove out that SQL Server is treating it as a `money` type:

```
select $ as n into #x

exec tempdb..sp_help '#x'
```

`sp_help` will output (among other things):

```
 Column_name     Type     Computed     Length     Prec     Scale     Nullable     TrimTrailingBlanks     FixedLenNullInSource     Collation    
 --------------  -------  -----------  ---------  -------  --------  -----------  ---------------------  -----------------------  ------------ 
 n               money    no           8          19       4         no           (n/a)                  (n/a)                    (null)
```